# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'transaction_sell_lines.name' in 'field list'

Tags: php, laravel

> DataTables warning: table id=product_sell_report_table - Exception Message:
>
> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'transaction_sell_lines.name' in 'field list'

Controller

```
$brands=DB::table('products') 
    ->select('brands.name') 
    ->join('brands','brands.id','=','products.brand_id')
    ->join('transaction_sell_lines','products.brand_id','=','transaction_sell_lines.product_id') 
    ->get();

'transaction_sell_lines.name as brand',

jQuery {data: 'brands',name:'transaction_sell_lines.brand'},
```

Comment: can you share the table structure with some data

Answer (score 1):

You need to give `DB::raw` to fetch such data

```
DB::raw('transaction_sell_lines.name as brand'),
```

Like above.

Now check again.

Comment: it won't fix the issue because he has error while selecting the columns

Comment: Have you ever selected column using `DB::raw`? If not give it a try, I suggest. For sake of Once check and then remove **DOWNVOTE**.

Comment: using raw query wont fix the issue

Comment: Here is documentation [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions) for your are concern. Once check question title. OP may not put all his snippet. But as a first impression I feel that way. If you have your own answer. You can post it. My question to you, have you faced such issue before? If yes, what you did? If no, how can you be sure about my snippet won't work?

Comment: i am saying that you code won't work because  he is trying to select the column form the table that doesen't exits so in the situation you need know the table structure so without that you can't give the solution.```DB::raw``` is for writing the raw mysql expression it will work perfectly but not related to the issue. The error clearly says that there is no such column in that table

Comment: If you see Op's snippet clearly, then you will know that it's not clean. Error he got must be from the snippet he doesn't posted. Hence, I am waiting for OP's reply.